# How can I use a length property in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

```
<td>${map.linkD2}person
    <s:set name="d2" >${map.linkD2 / map.d2 * 100}</s:set>
    <s:if test="d2.length => 4">
        <s:set name="perD2" value="#d2.substring(0,4)"></s:set>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <s:set name="perD2" value="#d2"></s:set>
    </s:else>
            ( ${perD2} )
</td>
```

I want to use `d2.length` but it doesn't work.  Why?

`d2.size()` also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`String` has a `length()` method. It's **not** a property. You're also missing the `#` before your variable name and your relational operator also needs to be `>=` instead of `=>`.

```
<s:if test="#d2.length() >= 4">
    <s:set name="perD2" value="#d2.substring(0,4)" />
</s:if>
```

Comment: Is `#` required before a variable name?

Answer (score 0):

Because `d2` is not a collection, and it doesn't have a property `length`. If you want to call a method use `length()` notation.

```
<s:if test="#d2.length() >= 4">
```

Note, if you create a variable using `set` tag and the value is assigned from the body of the tag it's converted to `String` before assignment and put into value stack context. The context variables should be accessed with `#` sign.

If it's converted to string you can't use this variable as numeric type. On the other hand if you use a `value` attribute of the `set` tag then the value is assigned as numeric, i.e. it preserve the type of the variable.

For example,

```
<s:set name="d2" value="%{map.linkD2 / map.d2 * 100}"/>
```

Then you should use `d2` as numeric type, i.e. it doesn't have `length()` method.